# C program: Wrote code to convert int to float, but it's giving me 0.0000 and it's changing my input to some strange number

Tags: c

I have the following piece of code, also available at [this link](https://ideone.com/FAJrm3).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("\nPlease input an integer to convert to float: %d", n );
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\nYour float is: %.5f", n);

    return(0);

}
```

What it's doing is not converting the float, it only gives me 0.0000, and it also takes my input and makes it some wacky number.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, even after looking around on different sites. 
I can't use any library, either, so nothing of atol, etc

Comment: Where do you convert your `int` to a `float`? Printing an `int` with a format for floats isn't conversion, it's undefined behaviour. (And `n` isn't initialised when you use it for the first time.)

Comment: `printf("\nYour float is: %.5f", n);` --> `printf("\nYour float is: %.5f", (double) n);`

Comment: There is no conversion done, merely UB from an incorrect specifier.

Comment: Just treating a bike like a plane doesn't make it fly.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("\nPlease input an integer to convert to float: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\nYour float is: %.5f", (float)n);

    return(0);
}
```

You have to explicitly write the cast, if you want an integer to be converted to a float in that way. If you don't, this causes undefined behavior. Another way is to declare a float variable and assign n to it.

By the way, the code you wrote shouldn't even compile without a warning on GCC.

Comment: Why not? I know it was "wrong" since `n` was unitialized and I've already changed that printf, but even with `-Wall` and `-Wextra` GCC gives me no warning. "Wrong" because it would just print garbage.

Comment: You could have tried `-O1` or even more optimisation. I did not downvote, BTW.

Comment: Only if I combine `-O1` with `-Wall`. But I don't think anyone would put `-O1` in a code like this. Also, you are provoking GCC to give a warning. Obviously, I was talking about passing an integer to printf while it expected a double.